# Abbreviations for pinyin and hepburn transliterations?

Tags: chinese, japanese, transliteration, standards

Are there 2 letter ISO codes for the pinyin or hepburn transliterations? If not, are there non-ISO abbreviations in common use? Thanks.

Comment: As I recall and from what I understand, Hepburn is not used for transliterating Chinese, but Japanese. I've been wrong before though.

Comment: Yes, I know this. I should have been more clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ISO has codes for languages ([ISO 639](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_639-2)), and for scripts ([ISO 15924](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_15924)); but it has no codes for transliterations, as you can see by perusing ISO's standards on [Writing and Transliteration](https://www.iso.org/ics/01.140.10/x/). ISO adopts and standardises transliterations; but unlike languages and scripts, it has not catalogued them.

Using existing ISO codes, *zh-Latn* means "Chinese in Latin Script", and *zh-CN-Latn* means "Chinese in Latin Script, localised to China"; but that just implies "Pinyin" (and what country would we attribute Hepburn to?) It is not a solution.

I can't find evidence that there are standard codes for transliterations anywhere else either. A 2011 [IETF RFC draft for transliteration codes](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-falk-transliteration-tags-01) went nowhere.

Comment: In GNU/Linux computer environments (or others using the GNU libc), locales can have "variants" following an at-sign.  So `uz` is Uzbek but `uz@cyrillic` is Uzbek in Cyrillic; Kashmir has `ks@aran` (Perso-Arabic script) and `ks@deva` (Devanagari), etc. There aren't any for transliterations so far, but this "variant" system isn't used just for scripts; it includes things like dialects (`sr@ijekavian`), typographic tuning (`en@quot`), even jokes (`en@piglatin`). Of course, this isn't any sort of standard; I'm only commenting the existence of this system for completeness' sake.

Answer (score 0):

ISO has some standard romanization systems listed at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_romanizations. Pinyin is **ISO 7098**, but unfortunately no other systems of Chinese romanizations have been given ISO codes so you may not find this useful.